# msbuild solution file

Tags: msbuild

I have created a msbuild file which will build a solution file(NOTE: not a project file). I would like to be able to change the debug and release target path in the msbuild file. How can i go about doing that? Thank you very much.

msbuild file

```
   <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <Target Name="deploy">
        <MSBuild Projects="foo.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release" ContinueOnError="false" />
      </Target>
    </Project>
```

Solution file Below:

```
 Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "foo", ".", "{3D958438-10F1-4211-BC7F-F0A5E5601C3F}"
        ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
            TargetFramework = "3.5"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/foo"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\foo\"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\PrecompiledWeb\foo\"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
            Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/foo"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\foo\"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\PrecompiledWeb\foo\"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
            Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
            VWDPort = "51644"
            DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual Basic"
        EndProjectSection
    EndProject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the output, set the OutDir property.  So instead of:

```
  Properties="Configuration=Release"
```

try:

```
  Properties="Configuration=Release;OutDir=d:\myCode\out\"
```